# Taking date as dd/mm/yy in C language and displaying date in "legal" form

Tags: c

My program works but doesn't accomplish its task. For example when I enter 12/11/20 as inputs, it gives this result: "Dated this 16th day of (null), 200."

How can I solve month and year part of my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int day, mon, year;
    char *months[] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

    printf("Enter date(DD/MM/YY): ");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &day, &mon, &year);

    if(day%10 == 1 && day != 11)
        printf("Dated this %dst day of %s, 20%d.", day, months[mon], year);

    else if(day%10 == 2 && day != 12)
        printf("Dated this %dnd day of %s, 20%d.", day, months[mon], year);

    else if(day%10 == 3 && day != 13)
        printf("Dated this %drd day of %s, 20%d.", day, months[mon], year);
    else
        printf("Dated this %dth day of %s, 20%d.", day, months[mon], year);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Program's result when I enter 16/11/20 as inputs]

Comment: `scanf("%d%d%d", &day, &mon, &year);` ==>  ``if (scanf("%d/%d/%d", &day, &mon, &year) != 3) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);``

Comment: It appears a *Matching-Failure* occurs that results in your reading `day`, but the remaining values failing. Since you do not check the return -- you have no way to know. You can't use any user-input function correctly if you fail to ***check the return***.

Comment: You are saying to enter the date with slashes bt then telling scanf there are no slashes.  So it gets to a slash and stops trying to extract numbers.  If you initialize your variables you will see that they aren't extracted.  This is why scanf returns an error code.

Comment: pmg's scanf should fix your issue.Side note , its months[mon-1] since arrays in c start from 0.